# How set a custom URL for a new theme file in WP?

Tags: php, site-url

I want to create a new theme file in wordpress. for example : index111.php
And I want to copy all the contents of one of the main template files (for example : index.php) into the new file (index111.php). And then I want to make changes to its codes.

And I want to set a URL for this file (index111.php) so that by entering this URL in the browser, this file will be loaded and displayed. for example : mysite.com/index111

I want to do this several times. For example, create 100 customized files with a dedicated URL.

My WP theme is Avada.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly create `index111.php` go to `mysite.com/index111`. Because the WordPress loading principal is like the following explanation. You could do similar things with custom templates but not exactly the `index111.php`. Also, it is assumed that you use [`permalinks`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/) too.

#### WordPress loading method

Because WordPress is running a query based system. That's means, basically it read links like `mysite.com/?p=1234` and find if there is any post with `1234`. If you turned on permalinks with `Post name` (settings -> permalinks) with `Post name` selected and saved.
Then it allows `mysite.com/something` where `something` is a page you have created in `Pages` menu on the left. It then try to match if there is a page `something` and find its id, if page exists, it loads, redirect to 404 if not. WordPress regard `something` as `slug`. When you create a page, a post, `slug` will be automatically generated based on the title you insert. Characteristic of a slug

- Editable
- Unique, if slug found in the database, WordPress will add number to your new slug. You could have pages with same title but their slug could not.

It is editable.

*** So what method to use depends on what did you try to accomplish.

To accomplish what you would like, there are many ways, here illustrate 2 simple methods which you could refer. If you understand the above concept well, there are still other ways to do so by using custom codes and more advanced methods.

---

#### by Template for Page Selection

Step to add

1. create a template page and save as filename `template-{$name}.php`
2. add a page and select this template from Template list on the right sidebar in the Edit Page menu

```
<?php
/**
 * The example template for index111, the following "index111" will be displayed from the selection menu
 *
 * Template Name: index111
 *
 * @package myPackage
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <!-- content here -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

pros

- could select page template from the edit page menu when adding a new page
- don't need to pre-create all pages
- could apply to many different pages with same template

---

#### by page-{$slug}.php template

You create page with same slug with the template file.
Steps

1. You add a page in Pages menu, name it with `index111` with slug `index111`,
2. create `page-index111.php` in your theme. Then when you go to `mysite.com/index111`, it will load page-index111.php.

pros

- could have custom template for each template

cons

- need to create each page to use respective template with same slug name
- if you need 100 templates, then you need to create 100 pages
- because it use slug to create, template name must be unique, if you would like to use same set of elements, you might need to add a separate files and the require it.

Comment: very very thanks. I used the second solution. It solved exactly my problem.